# Git repository split - total repository size increased in comparison to original

Tags: git, split, repository, size

The big project, consisting of several modules, was split using

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached \
--ignore-unmatch $(ls -w 100500 -xd ^(editor|shared|thirdparty) )" \
--prune-empty -- --all
```

and similar command for rest modules into 2 projects *A* and *B*

The size of .git repository for original (unsplit) copy is **100Mb**, size of .git in *A* is **89Mb** and size of .git in *B* is **110Mb**

For both projects **A** and **B** I used cleanup as

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

I don't really understand why original repo, being split into 2 copies, is **~2 times less** in size than sum of it's splits.

I tried to perform lookups for several files from **A** in **B** and realized that there are no such files in **A** but are matches in **B**. So it looks like files (at least those ones) are not duplicated. I used the command like

```
git log --all -- **/CryptoInterface.java
```

in order to lok for the files.

So the question - if original project was 100mb, I assume that A should be like 30mb, B should be like 70mb or at least sum of sizes A and B shound't be as much as 2 times bigger than original 100mb.

Are there something wrong with my assumptions? Perhaps we do have duplicates in projects **A** and **B**? How can we check that and find duplicate objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to repack your packages? Every time I need to delete dangling objects in git, I use the following commands

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/*
git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0
git repack -A -d
git prune
```